# SonataDoctrineORMAdminExtension.php

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

Am trying to install sonataAdminBundle in my symfony project, here is my composer.json file

Am following https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-3/doc/getting_started/installation.html

```
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "~2.0",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "2.2.x-dev"
```

I put this in my appkernel file

```
        new Sonata\CoreBundle\SonataCoreBundle(),
        new Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle(),
        new Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle(),
        new Sonata\AdminBundle\SonataAdminBundle(),
        new Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle(),
```

In my config.yml file

`sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts: [admin]`

Am having this issus

> ClassNotFoundException in SonataDoctrineORMAdminExtension.php line 29:
>   Attempted to load class "AbstractSonataAdminExtension" from namespace
>   "Sonata\AdminBundle\DependencyInjection". Did you forget a "use"
>   statement for another namespace?

Answer (score 1):

That's a Composer issue - the set of dependencies generated by Composer results in this bug.
As of time of this post, long-term support version of Symfony is 2.8.3. Here's set of commands commands that worked for me to get this version of Symfony running with Sonata Admin:

1. Install Symfony:

   ```
   $ symfony new my_project_name lts
   ```
2. Downgrade Sensio Generator bundle to version 2.3:

   ```
   $ composer require sensio/generator-bundle "2.3.*"
   ```
3. Install Sonata Admin bundle and its dependencies:

   ```
   $ composer require sonata-project/admin-bundle "2.3.*"
   $ composer require sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle "2.3.*"
   $ composer require sonata-project/jquery-bundle
   ```

   - For jquery-bundle, you may see error: `The child node "default_contexts" at path "sonata_block" must be configured.`  If you see it, go to the next step. When you done with next step, try to install jquery-bundle once again.
4. Do rest of the steps as described in Sonata admin installation docs [here](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-3/doc/getting_started/installation.html): register installed bundles in `app/AppKernel.php`, change `app/config/config.yml` and `app/config/routing.yml`, clear cache, and install assets.

After that, you should be able to run the app.